# Close the main div after button click in angular 2

Tags: angular

I want to close the main div on button click that is inside the main div.

Here is my code:-

```html
index.html

<div id="main">
<button type="button">Click Me!</button>

</div>




hello.component.ts

import {Component, View} from "angular2/core";

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './index.html',
  })
```

Comment: How about `*ngIf` with a boolean ?

Comment: @Maxime, Could you describe in detail ? I am new for angular2.

Comment: It's ok to test things and be curious but if you have no idea how to do that, you should really read the doc before trying to do anything else @Vikas (see Aakash answer but it'd be a good idea to read the doc, really).

Answer (score 1):

Change you code like this as Maxime suggested:

```html
    index.html

    <div id="main" *ngIf="hidediv">
    <button type="button" (click)="onclick()">Click Me!</button>

    </div>




    hello.component.ts

    import {Component, View} from "angular2/core";

    @Component({
      selector: 'my-app',
      templateUrl: './index.html',
      })

export class HelloComponent{
    hidediv:boolean=true;

     onclick(){
         this.hidediv=false;
    }
 }

<!-- end snippet -->
```